# Retrive model results ordered by SUM from relationship

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, one-to-many

Working with Laravel eloquent I have two models **Users** and **UserSocialMediaChannels** which have a 1 to many relationship something similar to the example bellow.
What I am trying to achieve is to get the users ordered by the number of total followers that each user has.
For example the results in the example bellow should show userB before userA as userB followers(25) is greater than usersA followers(15)

How can I sum for each user the followers for all social channels and then order my results? I need to do this when retrieving the results from the DB in order for the paginated results to be correct.

```
uid Name
10  userA
5   userB
```

---

```
id  uid   Name   channel name   followers
1   10    userA  Facebook          10
2   10    userA  Instagram          5
3    5    userB  Facebook          20
4    5    userB  Instagram          5
```

---

```
public function channels() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserSocialMediaChannels', 'uid');
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'uid');
}
```

---

In the example bellow I  can successfully get only the users that have at least one channel having the followers value > than 10.

```
$users = \App\Models\User::with('channels');

$users->whereHas('channels', function($query){
      $query->havingRaw('SUM(followers) > ?', 10);
}
```

I also tried without success for each user to sum all the channels followers fields as a new field. The idea was to sort the users by this new field.

```
$users->whereHas('channels', function($query){
      $query->select(DB::raw('sum(followers) as totals'));
});
```

Comment: When using the last `$users` query, do you get any errors, or data is not shown?

Comment: @zlatangoralija I'm not getting any errors and the data is there as before, but I am not seeing the new field `totals` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to sort the parent model(users) as per the `SUM` of the Followers which is in the `belongsTo` relation. For this, you need to get the `SUM` of the followers first in the Select clause of the parent model so that you will have the value on which you can perform the Order By.

```
$users = \App\User::with('channels')
            ->select('users.*', \DB::raw('(SELECT sum(followers) FROM channels WHERE users.id = channels.user_id ) as total_followers'))
            ->orderBy('total_followers', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You counted all the `followers` and you reference them as `totals` and you now have to use them in your query. This is not tested, but should work.

```
$users->whereHas('channels', function($query){
      $query->select(DB::raw('sum(followers) as totals'))
            ->orderBy('totals', 'ASC')
})->get();
```

Comment: I thought this would work as well. I don't see the `totals` referenced anywhere in the collection when dd($users), and results are not ordered.